# getdents() syscall implementation for rootkit

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

I plan to hook my own version of getdents() for my rootkit. Code is here:

```
asmlinkage int new_getdents(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent *dirp, unsigned int count)
{
    int nread;
    int bpos;
    struct linux_dirent *d;
    int (*orig_func)(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent *dirp, unsigned int count);
    t_syscall_hook *open_hook;

    open_hook = find_syscall_hook(__NR_getdents);
    orig_func = (void*) open_hook->orig_func;

    nread = (*orig_func)(fd, dirp, count);
    d = dirp;

    for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
      d = (struct linux_dirent *) ((char*)dirp + bpos);
      printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", d->d_name);
      bpos += d->d_reclen;
    }

    return nread;
}
```

I fail to understand the type cast in this line:       `d = (struct linux_dirent *) ((char*)dirp + bpos);`

Both `d` and `dirp` hold memory address for a linux_dirent struct. `d_reclen` contains length of the entry. If we receive `d_reclen` as 3, 5, 7, then entries would be present at dirp, dirp+3 /size(linux_dirent), (dirp+3/size(linux_dirent)+5/size(linux_dirent))...

So the line should be something like this then:            `d = (struct linux_dirent *) ((dirp + bpos)/size(linux_dirent));`

Why are we converting into (char *)?

```
typedef struct {
        unsigned long   d_ino;
        unsigned long   d_off;
        unsigned short  d_reclen;
        char            d_name[1];
} linux_dirent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the line should be something like this then: d = (struct linux_dirent *) ((dirp + bpos)/size(linux_dirent));

No - `dirp / sizeof(linux_dirent)` makes little sense, the offset of `dirp` from `0` has no relation to the size of the structure. Dividing memory address by the size of the structure... it's just some unrelated address.

You meant, like, to divide *only the offset* from the memory location, and then add the resulting pointer to the pointer. Well, along:

```
(char*)dirp + ((char*)(dirp + bpos) - (char*)dirp)/sizeof(linux_dirent)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^                                       = (char*)dirp + bpos * sizeof(linux_dirent)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        = bpos * sizoef(linux_dirent)

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  = bpos
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  = (char*)dirp + bpos
```

But... instead of incrementing the `dirp` pointer in `sizeof(linux_dirent)` steps, you can just increment it in 1 bytes steps. That's what the cast to `char*` is doing. `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. The following is true to the value:

```
dirp + bpos == (char*)dirp + bpos * sizeof(linux_dirent)
```

> Why are we converting into (char *)?

We are converting to `char *` to change how many bytes the `+` operator will increment. Short example:

```
int *a = 20;
       a + 5 == 20 + 5 * sizeof(int)
(char*)a + 5 == 20 + 5 * sizeof(char)   // sizeof(char) = 1, so:
(char*)a + 5 == 25
```

*Pointer arithmetic* is a good topic to research.

Comment: Thank you. `(char*)dirp + ((char*)(dirp + bpos) - (char*)dirp)/sizeof(linux_dirent)` makes a lot of sense. I can see why converting it into a char array is the better way.